# Example ad tag for Google Interactive Media Ads

Tags: video-streaming, ads

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Google IMA to show ads in videos on Android. The SDK is available from https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/googleandroid

While the example app does work the example ad tag URL that is provided with it does not work. Without a tag URL ads cannot be shown and it is very difficult to build and experiment with the API without one. I've been trying to search for an example ad tag URL that works but I've not been successful.

The add tag URL provided with the Android example (as well as with the HTML5 example) is:
http://ad.doubleclick.net/pfadx/AngelaSite;kw=html5linearnonlinear;sz=300x300;ord=5036130;dcmt=text/xml

For those who have adblock enabled:
ad[dot]doubleclick[dot]net/pfadx/AngelaSite;kw=html5linearnonlinear;sz=300x300;ord=5036130;dcmt=text/xml

That leads into server side error:

```
error on line 1 at column 31: AttValue: " or ' expected
```

Does anyone know where I could get a working tag URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample tag at http://ad.doubleclick.net/pfadx/AngelaSite;kw=html5linearnonlinear;sz=300x300;ord=5036130;dcmt=text/xml
has been reactivated. It should work now.